# activar vibracion en un fragment de android

Tags: android

Siguiendo con el desarrollo de una app, me encuentro en un fragment con unos botones. Quiero que al pulsar se produzca una vibracion, pero al introducirlo, me pone "cannot resolve VIBRATOR_SERVICE"....

```
public class AsientosFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener, View.OnClickListener {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

ImageView btnup;
ImageView btndown;
ImageView btnrear;
ImageView btnfront;
RadioButton rb1;
RadioButton rb2;
RadioButton rb3;
RadioButton rb4;
RadioButton rb5;
ImageView imgasiento;


int seleccionRadioBoton=1;
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public AsientosFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static AsientosFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    AsientosFragment fragment = new AsientosFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }




}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    System.out.println("AQUIIIIII");
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_asientos,container,false);


    btnup=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.btnup);
    btndown=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.btndown);
    btnrear=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.btnrear);
    btnfront=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.btnfront);
    rb1=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb2=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    rb3=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rb3);
    rb4=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rb4);
    rb5=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rb5);
    imgasiento=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgasiento);


    rb1.setOnClickListener(this);
    rb2.setOnClickListener(this);
    rb3.setOnClickListener(this);
    rb4.setOnClickListener(this);
    rb5.setOnClickListener(this);



    btnup.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btndown.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btnrear.setOnTouchListener(this);
    btnfront.setOnTouchListener(this);



    return view;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    MainActivity mainAct = (MainActivity) this.getActivity();
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) mainAct.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    if (mainAct.myThreadConnected != null) {

        switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.btnup:

            switch (seleccionRadioBoton){


                case 1:

                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "3".getBytes();
                        btnup.setImageResource(R.drawable.up2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);


                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "h".getBytes();
                        btnup.setImageResource(R.drawable.up1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }


                    break;

                case 2:

                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "7".getBytes();
                        btnup.setImageResource(R.drawable.up2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "ñ".getBytes();
                        btnup.setImageResource(R.drawable.up1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }

                    break;

                case 3:


                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "q".getBytes();
                        btnup.setImageResource(R.drawable.up2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "v".getBytes();
                        btnup.setImageResource(R.drawable.up1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }

                    break;

                case 4:


                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "t".getBytes();
                        btnup.setImageResource(R.drawable.up2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "Q".getBytes();
                        btnup.setImageResource(R.drawable.up1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;

                case 5:

                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "o".getBytes();
                        btnup.setImageResource(R.drawable.up2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "T".getBytes();
                        btnup.setImageResource(R.drawable.up1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;


            }








            break;

        case R.id.btndown:
            switch (seleccionRadioBoton){


                case 1:


                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "4".getBytes();
                        btndown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "j".getBytes();
                        btndown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:


                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "8".getBytes();
                        btndown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "z".getBytes();
                        btndown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:


                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "w".getBytes();
                        btndown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "b".getBytes();
                        btndown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:

                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "y".getBytes();
                        btndown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "w".getBytes();
                        btndown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }

                    break;

                case 5:

                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "p".getBytes();
                        btndown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "Y".getBytes();
                        btndown.setImageResource(R.drawable.down1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;


            }

            break;
        case R.id.btnrear:

            switch (seleccionRadioBoton){


                case 1:
                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "2".getBytes();
                        btnrear.setImageResource(R.drawable.left2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "g".getBytes();
                        btnrear.setImageResource(R.drawable.left1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "6".getBytes();
                        btnrear.setImageResource(R.drawable.left2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "l".getBytes();
                        btnrear.setImageResource(R.drawable.left1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "0".getBytes();
                        btnrear.setImageResource(R.drawable.left2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "c".getBytes();
                        btnrear.setImageResource(R.drawable.left1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "r".getBytes();
                        btnrear.setImageResource(R.drawable.left2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "m".getBytes();
                        btnrear.setImageResource(R.drawable.left1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;

                case 5:
                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "i".getBytes();
                        btnrear.setImageResource(R.drawable.left2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "R".getBytes();
                        btnrear.setImageResource(R.drawable.left1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;


            }

            break;
        case R.id.btnfront:
            switch (seleccionRadioBoton){


                case 1:
                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "1".getBytes();
                        btnfront.setImageResource(R.drawable.right2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "f".getBytes();
                        btnfront.setImageResource(R.drawable.right1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "5".getBytes();
                        btnfront.setImageResource(R.drawable.right2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "k".getBytes();
                        btnfront.setImageResource(R.drawable.right1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "9".getBytes();
                        btnfront.setImageResource(R.drawable.right2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "x".getBytes();
                        btnfront.setImageResource(R.drawable.right1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "e".getBytes();
                        btnfront.setImageResource(R.drawable.right2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "n".getBytes();
                        btnfront.setImageResource(R.drawable.right1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;

                case 5:
                    if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        byte[] envio = "w".getBytes();
                        btnfront.setImageResource(R.drawable.right2);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);

                    }else if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        byte[] envio = "E".getBytes();
                        btnfront.setImageResource(R.drawable.right1);
                        mainAct.enviarCadena(envio);
                    }
                    break;


            }

            break;
    }

    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    System.out.println("IEEEEEE");
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.rb1:
            if (checked) {
                seleccionRadioBoton=1;
                imgasiento.setImageResource(R.drawable.butaca1);
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(seleccionRadioBoton));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.rb2:
            if (checked){
                seleccionRadioBoton=2;
                imgasiento.setImageResource(R.drawable.butaca2);
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(seleccionRadioBoton));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.rb3:
            if (checked){
                seleccionRadioBoton=3;
                imgasiento.setImageResource(R.drawable.butaca3);
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(seleccionRadioBoton));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.rb4:
            if (checked){
                seleccionRadioBoton=4;
                imgasiento.setImageResource(R.drawable.butaca4);
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(seleccionRadioBoton));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.rb5:
            if (checked){
                seleccionRadioBoton=5;
                imgasiento.setImageResource(R.drawable.butaca5);
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(seleccionRadioBoton));
            }
            break;
    }
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

El vibrator se encuentra en el metodo ontouch...pero no consigo que lo coja bien....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta que agregues el contexto para que se pueda reconocer la constante **[VIBRATOR_SERVICE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)**:

```
Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE
```

Por lo tanto este sería tu código:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) mainAct.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

O también:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

Recuerda agregar el permiso para que funcione correctamente:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`

Answer (score 1):

no te olvides de agregar esto a tu manifest:`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`

Proba esto:

```
Vivrator vib = (Vibrator) getContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```